# Can styled-components be used to style a custom component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, custom-component

I need to adapt some styles to an already-made component `Button`, which looks like (I simplified the code).

`Button` it actually generates a `<button>` with the @3rd-company default styles

```
import { Button } from '@3rd-company/ui';

const desktopBtn = {
    width: '164px',
    height: '48px',
    marginRight: '20px',
  };

return (
   <>
    <Button style={desktopBtn}>
        My CTA goes here
    </Button>
  </>
)
```

The problem is that this adds inline-styles.

I'm trying to move those styles into an styled component:

```
import { Button } from '@3rd-company/ui';
import { styled } from 'styled-components';

const DesktopBtn = styled.Button`
    width: '164px';
    height: '48px';
    marign-right: '20px';
 `;

return (
   <>
    <DesktopBtn>
        My CTA goes here
    </DesktopBtn>
  </>
)
```

But I'm getting this error:

- IDE:
  [image: List item]
- Browser:
  [image: List item]

This can not be used on custom components? any workaround?

Comment: I think it should be like this `const DesktopBtn = styled.button`. For more info check this: 
https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: @PriyankKachhela no because this will use the native `button` not the `Button` that I imported

Comment: Ohh I missed that import statement of custom button component. My Bad. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check about extended style in [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles)...

Basically this might work

```js
import { Button } from '@3rd-company/ui';
import { styled } from 'styled-components';

const DesktopBtn = styled(Button)`
    width: '164px';
    height: '48px';
    margin-right: '20px';
 `;

return (
   <>
    <DesktopBtn>
        My CTA goes here
    </DesktopBtn>
  </>
)
```